# Adding objects to List with Struts2

Tags: java, forms, jsp, struts2

I am new to using struts2 framework and have some confusion with it. I have a form that submits to an action class. I want the fields submitted to be saved into a List of Customer list. In the action class I declared a List, defined the getModel method to return a List of Customer, and in the prepare method (I'm not sure if this is right) I added objects to list

JSP

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Add Account </title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>
            Customer details
   </h2>
<s:form action="AddCustomerAction" name="/example" method="post">
    <h1>
        <s:textfield label="Enter First Name" name="firstName" key="firstName" required="true" size="25"/>
    </h1>
    <h1>
        <s:textfield label="Enter Last Name" name="lastName" required="true" size="25" />
    </h1>

    <h1>
        <s:textfield label="Enter Address" name="address" required="true" size="25" />
    </h1>
    <h1>
       <s:select value ="state" name="state" list="stateList" label="Select State" listKey="code" listValue="desc" required="true"/>
    <h1>
    <h1>
        <s:textfield label="Enter City" name="city" required="true" size="25" />
    </h1>
    <h1>
        <s:textfield label="Enter Zipcode" name="zipcode" required="true" size="25" />
    </h1>

     <h1>
        <s:submit name="OK"/>
     </h1>
     </s:form>
</body>
```

Action class

```
package example;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AddCustomerAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven{

private Customer customer = new Customer();
private List<Customer> customerList;

public List<Customer> getModel()
{
    return customerList;
}

public String execute()
{
    this.printCustomer();
    return SUCCESS;
}

public void prepare(){
    customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    customerList.add(new Customer("first", "last"));
}


private void printCustomer(){
    System.out.println("First Name = "+customer.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("Last Name = "+customer.getLastName());
    System.out.println("Add = "+customer.getAddress());
    System.out.println("State = "+customer.getState());
    System.out.println("City = "+customer.getCity());
    System.out.println("Zipcode = "+customer.getZipcode());    
}
```

In the action class I want to save the information submitted from the form in the Customer List so I can iterate over it and display the data.

When I run this, firstname and lastName are null (even though i entered values).

is my approach (setting the getModel() and prepare() as I have) correct? what am i missing?

Comment: Try to use this as references.
[Struts 2: updating a list of objects from a form with model driven architecture][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028113/struts-2-updating-a-list-of-objects-from-a-form-with-model-driven-architecture

Comment: There are really A LOT of questions in your question. Read Struts2 docs, take what you still don't understand, organize it in a structured way, split it into multiple questions then ask them here (or search for them first). I can see now: 1) Sending - receiving parameters from / to JSP in Struts2; 2) Sending - receiving Lists; 3) Read parameters in prepare() method; 4) Manual objects instantiation 5) ModelDriven usage (that is useless to me, IMHO)...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about `List<Customer>`. Your form submits a `Customer` not a list of customer.
So

```
public Object getModel()
{
    return customerList;
}
```

If you want to get a list of customers, you must change your jsp and too.

Also to use `ModelDriven` actions, make sure that the `Model Driven Interceptor` is applied to your action.

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:textfield label="Enter First Name" name="firstName" key="firstName" required="true" size="25"/>
```

The name of this field is firstName and hence, it requires a getter/setter for a property/field named `firstName`

In order to get the customer bean filled up in your action with the parameters from the request, change the name to `customer.firstName`

and then you'll need a setter for `customer` field, which you already have.

The only assumption here is that you need to have a field named `firstName` in your customer class, but looking at `customer.getFirstName()` I guess you do have a field named `firstName` in your `customer` bean.

I tried to explain pretty clearly, on how the parameters get mapped from request to action, please let  me know if you didn't understand anything.