# How to send an object as check-box value from the checked row to Struts 2 action

Tags: java, jsp, checkbox, struts2

In my JSP page I've displayed list of people with `id`, `name` and `email` fields as follows:

```
<s:iterator value="peopleList">
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkedId"  value="<s:property value="id"/>" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="id"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="firstName"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="lastName"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="email"/></td>                        
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

My action class is as follows:

```
    private String[] checkedId;
    private List<People> peopleList;
    PeopleDao peopleDao = new PeopleDaoImpl();
    People people = new People();
    private List<People> checkBoxList = new ArrayList<People>();

 public String checkBox(){      

     System.out.println("Hello");
        for(String p: checkedId){
        System.out.println(p);
        }
         return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Currently I'm sending an `id` as check-box value and printing them out in action class. This works fine but what I want is to send the whole checked row of `id`, `name`s and email as an object of type `People` as check-box value to store it in `checkBoxList`. How do I achieve this?

I tried adding `var="list"` in the iterator and using the "list" as the value for check-box with `name="checkBoxList"` but it didn't work out.

Comment: Take a look at http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/processing-forms.html.

Answer (score 0):

In your html, keep the values of all the other attributes as hidden input tags in a form  so that when the user submits the form you can get all the attributes in the code.

```
<form id="peopleSelect" action="updateSelectedPpl.action">
<s:iterator value="peopleList">
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkedId"  value="<s:property value="id"/>" /></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="firstNames"  value="<s:property value="firstName"/>" /><s:property value="firstName"/></td>
    <!-- do the same for all the others -->
    <td><s:property value="id"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="lastName"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="email"/></td>                        
</tr>
</s:iterator>
</form>
```

your action class code can be like this. make sure your action class implements ServletRequestAware

```
String[] checkedIds = request.getParameterValues("checkedId");
String[] firstNames = request.getParameterValues("firstnames");

for(int i=0; i<checkedIds.size; i++){
  //get all the other attributes and populate your pojo here.
  firstName = firstNames[i];

}
```

Comment: What I wanted to know was if it was possible to send an object instead of having to send its fields like ids, names separately

Comment: yes, you can do that using ModelDriven. see this answer for more details http://stackoverflow.com/a/13031499/728610

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexed property names when submitting form data.

```jsp
<s:iterator value="peopleList" status="st">
<tr>
    <td><s:checkbox name="checkBoxList[%{#st.index}].checkedId"  value="%{id}" /></td>
    <td><s:textfield name="checkBoxList[%{#st.index}].id"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="checkBoxList[%{#st.index}].firstName"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="checkBoxList[%{#st.index}].lastName"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="checkBoxList[%{#st.index}].email"/></td>                        
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```