# How to fetch Data in ArrayList using ModelDriven

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, model-driven

Following are my POJO, `Action`, and JSP page.

For *single* instance of `Expense` I am getting proper input.

I would like to use `ModelDriven` to fetch multiple instance of `Expense` from JSP page.

For that I have created multiple `<div class="Expense">...</div>`, but I dont know what changes should I made in `Action` class.

How to achieve this?

**Pojo Class:**

```
public class Expense  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Long id;
     private Client client;
     private String param;
     private BigDecimal value;
     private Date dt;
     private Date adddate;
     //getter and setter
}
```

**Action Class:**

```
public class ExpenxeAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Expense> {

    Expense e = new Expense();
    ExpenseDAO dao = new ExpenseDAO();
    private LoginCheck lc = null;
    private List<Expense> expenseList = new ArrayList<Expense>();

    public String insertExpense() {
        dao.insert(e);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
   @Override
     public Expense getModel() {
    return e;
  }
}
```

**JSP page:**

```
 <div class="Expense">
    <label>Expense Type</label>
      <input type="text" name="param"  id="param"/>
     <label>Amount</label>
      <input type="text" name="value" class="form-control" id="value"/>
     <label>Date</label>
     <input type="text" name="dt" class="form-control"  id="dt"/>
   </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struts 2: updating a list of objects from a form with model driven architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028113/struts-2-updating-a-list-of-objects-from-a-form-with-model-driven-architecture)

Comment: And why do you use modeldriven?

Comment: @AleksandrM I find It easy to initialize object. Is there any other way to do so.

Comment: S2 will initialize object for you on submit. You don't need to do it yourself.

Comment: But with ModelDriven we can reuse POJO class

Comment: What do you mean *reuse POJO class*? You can *reuse* it w/o modeldriven.

Comment: What exactly? BTW use @xrcwrn to mention somebody. W/o it person will not be notified.

Comment: Ok Without ModelDriven I will create Object for Pojo and then I will use pojo class in My action Is it correct way Without using ModelDriven

Answer (score 0):

You should create a getter for `expenseList`

```
public List<Expense> getExpenseList() {
  return expenseList;
}
```

in the JSP use indexed property names

```
<s:iterator value="expenseList" status="stat">
   <div class="Expense">
     <label>Expense Type</label>
     <s:textfield name="expenseList[%{#stat.index}].param"  id="param"/>
     <label>Amount</label>
     <s:textfield name="expenseList[%{#stat.index}].value" class="form-control" id="value"/>
     <label>Date</label>
     <s:textfield name="expenseList[%{#stat.index}].dt" class="form-control"  id="dt"/>
   </div>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: If I am adding `<s:iterator value="expenseList" status="stat">` at Add.jsp page it is not showing any content between `<iterator>`

Comment: Use `theme="simple"` on the form tag or globally.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch array list of Expense objects in action class you need to make the following changes to your code.

1. First you have to change `ModelDriven<Expense>` to  `ModelDriven<List<Expense>>` and remove `Expense e = new Expense();`, if you wish. So, finally your action class should look like this.

   ```
   public class ExpenxeAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<List<Expense>>, Preparable {
       ExpenseDAO dao = new ExpenseDAO();
       private LoginCheck lc = null;
       private List<Expense> expenseList = new ArrayList<Expense>();

       public String insertExpense() {
           for (Expense e : expenseList) {     //loop to iterate over each elements
               dao.insert(e);
           }
           return SUCCESS;
       }
       public List<Expense> getExpenseList() {
           return expenseList;
       }

       public void setExpenseList(List<Expense> expenseList) {
           this.expenseList = expenseList;
       }   

      @Override
       public void prepare() throws Exception {
           expenseList = new ArrayList<Expense>(); 
       }

       @Override
       public List<Expense> getModel() {
           return expenseList;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Now, you have to make changes to your jsp page.

   ```
   <div class="Expense">
       <label>Expense Type</label>
       <input type="text" name="model[0].param"  id="param"/>
       <label>Amount</label>
       <input type="text" name="model[0].value" class="form-control" id="value"/>
       <label>Date</label>
       <input type="text" name="model[0].dt" class="form-control"  id="dt"/>

       <label>Expense Type</label>
       <input type="text" name="model[1].param"  id="param"/>
       <label>Amount</label>
       <input type="text" name="model[1].value" class="form-control" id="value"/>
       <label>Date</label>
       <input type="text" name="model[1].dt" class="form-control"  id="dt"/>

       <label>Expense Type</label>
       <input type="text" name="model[2].param"  id="param"/>
       <label>Amount</label>
       <input type="text" name="model[2].value" class="form-control" id="value"/>
       <label>Date</label>
       <input type="text" name="model[2].dt" class="form-control"  id="dt"/>
   </div>
   ```

You will notice that in the jsp code we have mentioned

> `model[index].<pojo_member_variable_name>` instead of specifying of
>   `lstExp[index].<pojo_member_variable_name>`

This is because now we want struts2 to set the values directly into these member variables. So we have mentioned `model[index].<pojo__member_variable_name>` so that struts2 should automatically set the value into the list. Here in the above code we are creating list of 3 `Expense` Object. If you need to insert more values then just increment the index and set the values and remaining will be done by struts2 for you.